# How to develop in Visual Studio 2008 and embed Report Viewer Object for .Net 2?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, sql-server-2005, reporting-services, reportviewer, reportingservices-2005

Application is being developed in `VS 2008`. Report viewer is used and calls a report from SSRS on a `SQL Server 2005` server.

```
Error:
Server Error in '/AppName' Application. 

Configuration Error 
Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately. 

Parser Error Message: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Source Error: 
Line 41: <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=9.0.0.0
```

My guess is that it's because of the `.Net 3.5` vs `.Net 2.0` thing. The Application Server doesn't have `3.5` and will not.

How do you fix `VS 2008` so that it will use a Report Viewer appropriate for `.Net 2` applications?

Answer (score 0):

If you set Copy Local = True for the ReportViewer reference in your project then the required version of the dll will be copied to your bin folder when you publish.

See http://dotnetslackers.com/_NET/re-100203_Error_Could_not_load_file_or_assembly_Microsoft_ReportViewer_WebForms_Version_9_0_0_0.aspx for more details.

Answer (score 0):

We solved this issue by putting both the 2005 Report Viewer and 2008 report viewer on the server. Thanks for the response.